# How to handle progress dialog correctly in android?

Tags: java, android

I am new in android and java. I am in a trouble in implementing progress dialog correctly.

I have a code like this

```
   ProgressDialog dialog= new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
   dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
   dialog.setMax(100);
   dialog.show();
   MY METHOD WHICH GRABS DATA FROM INTERNET;
   dialog.dissmiss();
```

but by implementing this, my method runs well but no progress dialog is visible, again when i comment out the dismiss method, the dialog doesnt stop and i had to force close the app,then how to use this dialog? in aditional dont want to bring any thread here, is there any way to use dialog without any thread? Thanks

Comment: [Here is perfect guide for that](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog)

Answer (score 4):

Problem here is that any long running tasks such as fetching data from the Internet must be run inside a separate thread, otherwise you're likely to get an ANR if your code runs for more then 5 seconds. The ideal solution in my opinion is to implement an `AsyncTask`: it lets you run tasks in a separate thread and helps you easily update your UI thread, showing `ProgressDialog`s or `ProgressBar`s to let your users know that your app is currently busy. Simply place all your `ProgressDialog` initialization code inside the `onPreExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask`, and the `dialog.dismiss()` call to `onPostExecute()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I m trying this one and I will let you know

Comment: Can you please give me a proper example to asynctask?

Comment: @SabbirAhmed, Yes, this post was useful for me: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you no need to use Thread class. You can use AsyncTask instead. Start the progress dialog when you call the AsyncTask, dismiss it in the postExecute method.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer AsyncTask for progress dialog.

In your onPreExecute, create your above code. In doInBackground, do your background tasks and in onPostExecute display an alertdialog saying work done !

Comment: I have done what u said, but onPreExecute methods dialod is not dismissed and also backgrond work is not happening

Comment: In  your doInBackground, you should say dialog.dismiss() after your work is done

Comment: Dont dismiss it in onPreExecute